# LEFT JOIN two tables so that left table data is filtered but right table data is displayed even if left table data does not exist

Tags: mysql

To allow our customers to store some of their own data along with our data structure I have created two extra tables:

```
CREATE TABLE external_columns
(
  `id`      INT(11)     PRIMARY KEY   NOT NULL,
  `column`  VARCHAR(30)               NOT NULL,
  `sid`     INT(11)                   NOT NULL,
  `bid`     INT(11)                   NOT NULL,
  `label`   VARCHAR(30)               NOT NULL,
  `table`   VARCHAR(30)               NOT NULL,
  `default` TINYTEXT                  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE external_data
(
    `id`         INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    `extcol_id`  INT(11)             NOT NULL,
    `sid`        INT(11)             NOT NULL,
    `bid`        INT(11)             NOT NULL,
    `data`       MEDIUMTEXT          NOT NULL,
    `row_id`     INT(11)             NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `external_data_external_columns_id_fk` 
      FOREIGN KEY (extcol_id) REFERENCES external_columns (id)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX combinedUniqueIndex 
  ON external_data (extcol_id, sid, bid, row_id);
```

`sid` and `bid` are system values that identify the customer the data belongs to. `row_id` refers to the primary key of table referenced in `table`.

To get data for a certain row I have created this prepared statement:

```
SELECT `data`.*, `columns`.`column`, `columns`.`default`
FROM `external_columns` as `columns`
  LEFT JOIN `external_data` as `data`
    ON `columns`.`id` = `data`.`extcol_id`
WHERE (
      `columns`.`sid`   = :sid
  AND `columns`.`bid`   = :bid
  AND `data`.`row_id`   = :row_id
  AND `columns`.`table` = :tableName
)
```

This works fine as long as for each `external_column` there is an entry in `external_data` for the given `:row_id`. But I want to make sure that there is always a row for each `column`, even if there is no data for the given `:row_id`. Is there a way to do this with one query?

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and move the condition from `WHERE` to the join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close, by placing `AND data.row_id   = :row_id` in your WHERE, you have effectively written an INNER JOIN as nulled `data.row_id`s won't match.

You should move this condition to the LEFT JOIN conditions:

```
   SELECT `data`.*, `columns`.`column`, `columns`.`default`
     FROM `external_columns` as `columns`
LEFT JOIN `external_data` as `data`
       ON `data`.`extcol_id`= `columns`.id
      AND `data`.`row_id`   = :row_id
    WHERE `columns`.`sid`   = :sid
      AND `columns`.`bid`   = :bid
      AND `columns`.`table` = :tableName
```

**Personal Preferences:**

Don't need the WHERE parentheses and I always tend to put the table conditions for a JOIN in the JOIN conditions where applicable and JOIN table on the LHS to make indexing options more obvious..

No difference for INNER JOINs but essential for certain LEFT JOINs.